# How to replace an object in an array of object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

Iam working on React.js.
I have an array of objects `clientList`.
I am trying to update the function of creating a new client with the option to update an existing client object present in `ClientList` and replace it with the new data entered by the user.
I cant figure out how to do it. I tried to map on the clientList and find if the username entered by the user is similar to the one present in one of the objects in the`ClientList` array then replace it with the `newClient`created . It works for the first index but for the following ones it only copies the same object each time it finds similar user value.

Here is my code :

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  const [pwd, setPwd] = useState();
  const [currentClient, setcurrentClient] = useState();
  const [clientList, setClientList] = useState([]);

//function to add and update client

  const addClient = (idNum, user, password, money) => {

    const newClient = new Client(idNum, user, password, money);

    setcurrentClient(newClient);

    setClientList([...clientList, newClient]);

    console.log(currentClient);
    console.log(clientList);

    const result = clientList.map((obj, i) =>
      obj.username === user ? newClient : obj
    );
    console.log(result);
```

Here is the result I got:

```
(3) [Client, Client, Client]
0: Client {purchaseList: Array(1), id: '123456788', username: 'aaaa a', password: 'Aaaa', moneyAmount: '3'}
1: Client {purchaseList: Array(1), id: '123456788', username: 'aaaa a', password: 'Aaaa', moneyAmount: '3'}
2: Client {purchaseList: Array(1), id: '123456788', username: 'aaaa a', password: 'Aaaa', moneyAmount: '3'}
length: 3
```

I would have expected that the 3 times I tried to update the object that has username 'aaaa a', it would have updated my array with only the object created. But instead it saves 3 times the same object with username 'aaaa a' with the last object values entered.

Comment: That is because you are adding new client every time to your list, in this line  `setClientList([...clientList, newClient]);`   set temporary variable using spread operator, then find client by id and then update the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another way as I said before. You can use a temporary variable and work with it.

```
const addClient = (idNum, user, password, money) => {
    const newClient = new Client(idNum, user, password, money);
    setcurrentClient(newClient);
    let temp = [...clientList]
    if (temp.some((obj) => obj.idNum === idNum)) {
      temp = temp.map((obj) =>
        obj.idNum === idNum ? newClient : obj
      );
      setClientList(temp)
    }
    else {
      setClientList([...clientList, newClient])
    }
}
```

Comment: @Yehoudith Polony Note this could result in bugs if `addClient` is ever called in quick succession before the result of one of them is flushed by react since it doesn't use the callback form of setState.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the client to the client list by calling `setClientList` and then you are doing some operation afterwards -- but at that point, it's too late. You need to make an active choice on if to add it to the list of replace it *before* setting it.

```
  const addClient = (idNum, user, password, money) => {

    const newClient = new Client(idNum, user, password, money);

    setcurrentClient(newClient);

    setClientList((prevClientList) => {
       if (prevClientList.some((obj) => obj.id === idNum)) { // This checks if an entry with the same ID already exists
           // If it does, return a map with the matched item replaced
           return prevClientList.map((obj) =>
              obj.id === idNum ? newClient : obj
           );
       }

       
       // If it doesn't add it to the list
       return [...prevClientList, newClient]
    });
```

By the way, as used above, you should use the callback form of the state setter when deriving a new value from its current value, to prevent bugs that can happen in regard to stale data in React.

Additionally, probably better to use the ID as the thing to check against as typically slightly stronger guarantees than username.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am really new at react it feels really hard for a beginner like me to order the steps...so again thank you for your help:)